# Gfortran installed but no executable made

Tags: gcc, fortran, installation, gfortran

I am having trouble installing gfortran on my computer. My OS is windows, and I've gotten gfortran downloaded and working in the windows terminal. However, I am using MobaXterm and I cannot get it to work there.

I installed gfortran and it works in the windows terminal, but MobaXterm does not find it (i.e. `gfortran --version` gives an error). I tried installing gfortran in MobaXterm instead by using `apt-cyg install  gcc-fortran`. Gfortran is now recognized, but when I try to compile, no executable is produced (that I can find).

This is what comes up when I type `gfortran -v` in MobaXterm:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/bin/gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.9.2-3.i686/src/gcc-4.9.2/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.9.2-3.i686/src/gcc-4.9.2 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which command do you execute? Which simple source code are you compiling? (Try just a simple example with one `end`) Show us the examples so that we can diagnose. What does `gfortran -v` print?

Comment: This is what is printed when I type `gfortran -v`: This is what is printed when I type `gfortran -v`: Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/bin/gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin... The whole thing won't fit in the comment. I was just trying to compile a simple program that calculates the area of a circle. I know it works because it works in the windows terminal. There is just no executable created when I try to compile in MobaXterm

Comment: What is the command you use to compile your program?